# Conflicting peer dependancy: eslint-plugin-vue@7.20.0

Tags: vue.js, heroku, eslint, peer-dependencies, eslint-plugin-vue

I am getting a conflicting peer dependency: eslint-plugin-vue@7.20.0 when trying to build/deploy my Vue CLI application using Heroku:

```
       npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
       npm ERR! peer eslint-plugin-vue@"^7.0.0" from @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
       npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-standard
       npm ERR!   dev @vue/eslint-config-standard@"^6.1.0" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint-plugin-vue@7.20.0
       npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue
       npm ERR!   peer eslint-plugin-vue@"^7.0.0" from @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
       npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-standard
       npm ERR!     dev @vue/eslint-config-standard@"^6.1.0" from the root project
```

I tried running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps --save`, but this did not fix the issue.

Comment: run `npm install --force`

Answer (score 2):

In your project folder, run:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps=true --location=projectr
```

According to: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4664#issuecomment-1086096726

I installed tailwind smoothly, after a similar error appeared.